# How to use $db instead of $GLOBALS['db'] in my classes?

Tags: php, oop, class

I need to use `$GLOBALS['db']` in my classes (`$db` is defined in my index.php), but I don't want to use `$GLOBALS['db']` when I have to call it.

I wrote this code at the beginning of my classes :

```
class ClassName
{
    var $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = $GLOBALS['db'];
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $val = $this->db->oneValue('SELECT first_name FROM users LIMIT 0, 1');
        echo $val->first_name;
    }
}
```

But I'm not enjoying this; I prefer to use directly `$db` in my code. Is there a solution to be able to call `$GLOBALS['db']` by `$db`?

Comment: This is quite the antipattern. Conside using IoC/DI: `public function __construct($db) { $this->db = $db; }`

Comment: The OP doesn't really explain why he MUST use $GLOBAL, even a global singleton would be less evil!

Comment: you don't like this single call in the coinstructor or don't like $this->db instead of $db?

Comment: also `var` is deprecated use `public|private|protected`

Comment: Thanks :). And @LawrenceCherone: thank you, I'll do that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simples, just inject in the constructor or a setter method: (I'm assuming $db is an object here, not an array of connection parameters etc)

```
class ClassName
   {
   protected $db;

   public function __construct($db)
   {
       $this->setConnection($db);
       //Any other constructor things you want to happen...
   }

   /*
    * This is just here for convenience, this could be protected if you only want to set 
    * the db connection via the constructor
    */
   public function setConnection($db)
   {
       $this->db = $db;
   }    

   public function test()
   {
       $val = $this->db->oneValue('SELECT first_name FROM users LIMIT 0, 1');
       echo $val->first_name;
   }
}
```

As mentioned in some comments above, this is a form of dependency injection which will give you more ability to re-use code inside your project (A Good Thing TM).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question so fast. Can I make something like `class ClassName extends Database` and set the connection in the `Database` class? I would access my function by `$this->dbOneValue()` for example. Is it a good idea?

Comment: i personally hate it to pass the argument `$dbh` through constructor everytime i want to use it.

Comment: You can have your class extend a generic DB class, however you would still need to set the `$db` explicitly when you created a new `ClassName` as PHP uses classical inheritance, not Prototypal like Javascript. All the functions you create in the generic DB class will be accessible in the 'ClassName' class. Does that help?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, thats where factories and DI containers, Service Locators etc etc can come in handy but they are a little outside the scope of the question/answer.

Comment: i recommend to move the `setConnection` in your construct and pass $db by ref

Comment: As long as $db is an object (i've belatedly put that assumption in the code now) it should be passed by reference anyway shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using singleton pattern for databases.

this is the DB class i am using for my app.

```
class Database {

    protected static $_dbh;
    const HOST = 'localhost';
    const DATABASE = 'dbname';
    const USERNAME = 'username';
    const PASSWORD = 'password';

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset($_dbh)) {
            try {
                #Connection String.
                self::$_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::HOST.';dbname='.self::DATABASE,self::USERNAME,self::PASSWORD);
                self::$_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                #Print Errors.
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$_dbh;
    }
}
```

as i am using singleton pattern the connection will be re-used. you can now use the connection everywhere in your app by calling static connection method i.e

```
class ClassName
{
    protected static $_dbh;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$_dbh = Database::getInstance();
    }

    public function test() {
        $sth = self::$_dbh->query('SELECT first_name FROM users LIMIT 0, 1');
        $row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row['first_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: SINGLETON ANTI-PATTERN USAGE ALERT... This gives you no ability to (re)configure you database connection without changing code, and it also limits you to only one connection (not necessarily a bad thing), unless you copy-paste this into another singleton class (thus breaking DRY). Also, it means you are putting you database credentials into source control, which should be avoided. Also Unit Testing with singletons is a nightmare.

Comment: @JamesButler: Unit testing with singletons is _not_ a nightmare in 2011; stop regurgitating the same old tired nonsense.

Comment: Ok - valid point, its a nightmare in the pre "late static binding" era, but so many hosting companies are still yet to get beyond PHP 5.2, and I feel the OP is likely to be constrained by such considerations.

Comment: well, i am not sure if someone uses or create more than one database connection in an app unless they have a solid reason to do so. and i guess the OP was using the global variable `$GLOBALS['db']` for the same reason.